# Parent state getting reset back to initial value after different child is clicked

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend, react-functional-component, react-state

I have a parent and child components. Whenever the Link in the child component is clicked, I want to execute the parent's click handler that is passed in as props. In the click handler, I simply want to increment an integer state in the parent component.

The issue: the `numCars` state is correctly incremented for each single Link (child component) I click. For instance, if I click on the Link "car1" 5 times, the `numCars` state is incremented to 5. **However**, if I *then* click on "car2", the `numCars` state is reset back to 0. If I continue clicking "car2", `numCars` is incremented properly, until I click on another car. It's as if each child has its own parent component.

Why is this happening?

```
export default function Garage() {
   const [numCars, setNumCars] = useState(0);

   const carHandleClick = (carName) => {
      console.log("Clicked by " + carName); 
      setNumCars(numCars + 1);
   } 

   const cars = [
      {
         name: "car1"
      },
      {
         name: "car2"
      },
      {
         name: "car3"
      }
   ]

   return (
      <ul>
         {cars.map((car) =>
            <Car name={car.name} carHandleClick={carHandleClick}/>   
         }
      <ul>
   );
}

export default function Car( {name, carHandleClick} ) {
   return (
      <li>
         <Link to=... onClick={() => carHandleClick(name)}
            {name}
         </Link>
      </li>
   )
}
```

Comment: Does the behavior change when you use `const` to declare `carHandleClick` as a local variable with function scope? I wonder whether the variable became [automatically global](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: One more guess: What happens if you make the `Car`s distinguishable for React? `cars.map((car) => <Car` **`key={car.name}`** `name={car.name} carHandleClick={carHandleClick}/>`

Comment: That doesn't change it either.

Comment: In `carHandleClick()`, I can debug and see that `numCars` is the correct, incremented value before `setNumCars()` is called. I have a `console.log` statement above the `return` statement in `Garage`, and it shows the reset value of 0.

This makes me think `setNumCars()` is resetting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
carHandleClick = (carName) => {
 setNumCars(prev => prev + 1);
}
```

you want always to use the functional form of the state setter if you want to update it based on its previous value

or a useCallback hook with `[numCars]`:

```js
carHandleClick = useCallback((carName) => {
setNumCars(numCars + 1);
},[numCars])
```

---

**Update:**
the issue was related to the fact navigate with the link unmounts and remounts the parent component so its state is reset.
one way to handle this is to use a context in the top level:

```js
export const MyContext = createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [numCars, setNumCars] = useState(0);
  const carHandleClick = (carName) => {
    console.log("Clicked by " + carName);
    setNumCars((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ numCars, carHandleClick }}>
      //...
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

now you juste consume it from both parent and child:

```js
import { MyContext } from "./App";

export default function Garage() {
  const { carHandleClick, numCars } = useContext(MyContext);

  //...
  return (
    <ul>
      {cars.map((car) => (
        <Car name={car.name} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

```js
import { MyContext } from "./App";

function Car({ name }) {
  const { carHandleClick, numCars } = useContext(MyContext);
  //...
  return (
    <li>
      <Link onClick={() => carHandleClick(name)}>{name}</Link>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Learn more about [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext)

Comment: That still doesn't change it.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth try it with useCallback

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: this is weired to be honest, even your code should work, are you sure providing everything ?

Comment: I think I am. Do you think the issue is elsewhere?

Comment: the only explanation is that when you navigate with your link, the parent component unmounts then remounts, this will reset its numCars state to 0

Comment: Okay...so what would be the fix for that?

Comment: first please try without the `to` property of the Link and see

Comment: That works....so the redirection is unmounting and remounting the parent component?? By the way, my actual code is more complicated and I need the 'to'.